# C equality of constant strings

Tags: c

Is the following comparison guaranteed to be **true**?

```
"hello world"=="hello world";
```

Also, is the following always guaranteed to be **false**?

```
char a[] = "hello world";
a == "hello world";
```

Comment: strings, irregardless of their physical location must be compared using one of the string functions, like strcmp( "hello world", "hello world" );  I.E. the comparison operator '==' will only be comparing the address(s) of the arrays, which may or may not be identical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be clear - in both cases you are comparing pointers, not the actual string contents.

for

```
"hello world"=="hello world";
```

it is permitted that the comparison be `true` or `false`. The C standard says in 6.4.5 "String literals":

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values.

So the standard allows the storage for the literals to be the same or different.

For

```
char a[] = "hello world";
a == "hello world";
```

the comparison will always be `false` since the address of the array `a` must be different than the address of the string literal.

Comment: some additional information regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/q/17909417/532208

Answer (score 1):

In C you have to use a function that compare the strings for you. Doing it straigh away will only tell you if two strings are in the same place on the memory.
so

```
char a[] = "hello world";
char b[] = a;
```

the making

```
a == b;
```

will give you true because both a and b have point to the same place, or string, in the memory.

If you want to compare two strings you'll have to use `strcmp()` that returns 0 if the strings are equal.

```
if( strcmp(a, b) == 0 )
    printf("True\n");
else
    printf("False\n");
```

To use it you'll need to include the library string.h.

```
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing string contents is not allowed through `==` operator in C.
You should use

```
strcmp(str1,str2);
```

In this case you are comparing pointers.
So

```
"hello world" == "hello world";
```

may or may not be TRUE.

But the second case is always FALSE.

```
char a[] = "hello world";
a == "hello world";
```

Comment: That's not the question. To be precise, it's legal to use `==` to compare strings, but the result is comparing pointers, not the string content.

Comment: What YuHao said is right. In addition,`stcmp(str1,str2)` is wrong too!(typo)

Comment: @YuHao Agree == can be used to compare pointers as in this case. But it doesn't make sense to compare pointers as done here. So the intention I guess here is to compare string contents so I suggested ti use strcmp()

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator in C can be used to compare primitive data types. Since String are not primitive in C,you can't use the `==` to compare them. The best option is to use the `strcmp()` function by including `string.h` library.